# vectorization / parallelization of the computation of pairwise distances with a given function

Tags: pandas, performance, parallel-processing, vectorization, processing-efficiency

I have a problem, namely efficient computation of some distance function d(xi,xj) for all pairs i < j.

I have a list tr of trajectories, in the form of a numpy array, in which a row contains the latitude and longitude. The distance between two trajectories tri and trj is the DFD (discrete Frechet distance). I've found one implementation [here](https://github.com/bguillouet/traj-dist), but if there's a more efficient version, suggestions are very welcome.

```
import numpy
import pandas
import time 
import traj_dist.distance as td

m=10; n=1000; 
tr=[numpy.concatenate([180*numpy.random.random_sample((n-i,1))-90,
                       360*numpy.random.random_sample((n-i,1))-180],axis=1) for i in range(m)]    
t0=time.perf_counter(); 
dd=[td.discret_frechet(tr[i],tr[j]) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1,m)]; 
t1=time.perf_counter(); print(t1-t0)
dd=td.pdist(tr,metric="discret_frechet")
t2=time.perf_counter(); print(t2-t1)
```

Already for m=10 and n=10000 the code is way too slow. Is there a way to **parallelize** or **vectorize** it? Also, is there an implementation of DFD which uses the haversine distance between points?

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions:

```
import time
import numpy
import multiprocessing as mp
import ray; ray.init(memory=1*1024*1024*1024,object_store_memory=1*1024*1024*1024)
import traj_dist.distance as td #for computing distance between trajectories, see https://github.com/bguillouet/traj-dist

m=20; n=1000; tr=[numpy.random.rand(n,2) for i in range(m)]   #trajectories
def ti(): return time.perf_counter()

t0=ti(); d=td.pdist(tr,    metric="discret_frechet"); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0,d[:10]) #(m over 2) vector of dist(tri,trj) where tri, trj in tr
t0=ti(); d=[td.discret_frechet(tr[i],tr[j]) for i in range(m) for j in range(i+1,m)]; t1=ti(); print(t1-t0,numpy.array(d[:10])) 

def f(ti,tj): return td.discret_frechet(ti,tj) #must be at top level (not inside another function)
t0=ti(); pl=mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()); d=pl.starmap(f,[(tr[i],tr[j]) for i in range(m) for j in range(i+1,m)]); pl.close(); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0,numpy.array(d[:10]))

@ray.remote
def g(ti,tj): return td.discret_frechet(ti,tj)
t0=ti(); d=ray.get([g.remote(tr[i],tr[j]) for i in range(m) for j in range(i+1,m)]); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0,numpy.array(d[:10]))
```